# Add tick labels on x axis

Tags: r

Hi I plotted a histogram:

```
hist(start$newname2, xlab= "Time", xlim=c(6.0, 16.0),breaks=50, axis(1, at=1))
```

The result is[image]

I want the x axis to have labels for each integer: 6,7,8,9, etc. and not 6,8,10... I read the documentation for axis, so used at=1, but it does not change anything. I also tried to add tick=TRUE but the graph stays the same. I perhaps misinterpreted something.

Comment: try `axis(1, at=6:16)`

Comment: I tried. It gives me:  Warning messages:
1: In if (freq) x$counts else x$density :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: in another call (`hist(...);axis(1, at=6:16)`); If it doesn't work please provide a reproducible example, here we don't have data to "play" with...

Comment: It worked as a separate call. Thanks a lot.